# Tidygraph: obtain sequence of nodes along shortest path

Tags: r, tidyverse, igraph, tidygraph

I would like to obtain the sequence of nodes along the shortest path between two nodes using tidygraph. Consider this example.

```
library(tidygraph)
library(tidyverse)
demo_netw <- tbl_graph(nodes = tibble(node_id = c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                       edges = tribble(~from, ~to,
                                       "B", "A",
                                       "D", "C",
                                       "A", "D"))
shortest_path_from_B_to_C <-
  demo_netw %>%
  convert(to_shortest_path, node_id == "B", node_id == "C")
shortest_path_from_B_to_C

## # A tbl_graph: 4 nodes and 3 edges
## #
## # A rooted tree
## #
## # Node Data: 4 x 2 (active)
##   node_id .tidygraph_node_index
##   <chr>                   <int>
## 1 A                           1
## 2 B                           2
## 3 C                           3
## 4 D                           4
## #
## # Edge Data: 3 x 3
##    from    to .tidygraph_edge_index
##   <int> <int>                 <int>
## 1     2     1                     1
## 2     4     3                     2
## 3     1     4                     3
```

The output shows that the nodes `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are on the shortest path, but it does not show that the sequence of nodes is `B -> A -> D -> C`. The returned edge data does not reveal the sequence of the edges either.

I am aware that I can accomplish such tasks with igraph.

```
library(igraph)
demo_igraph <-
  demo_netw %>%
  activate(edges) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  graph_from_data_frame()

# We cannot easily access the node_id column, so we must manually make the
# mapping "B" -> "2", "C" -> "3"
shortest_paths(demo_igraph, "2", "3")$vpath

## [[1]]
## + 4/4 vertices, named, from a854191:
## [1] 2 1 4 3
```

However, this is inelegant for several reasons.

- I am looking for a tidygraph solution that does not resort to other packages.
- When exporting the tidygraph edge data, the information contained in the node data column `node_id` is lost, so I must either manually make the mapping "B" -> "2", "C" -> "3" or write much more elaborate code to join the information from the node and edge data.
- I would like the output to be `"B" "A" "D" "C"`, not `2 1 4 3`.

Is there some straightforward way to obtain the sequence of nodes along the shortest path directly with tidygraph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** It is possible to use any name as the `node_key` parameter, which will result in a successful construction of a `tbl_graph`. However, passing this onto `igraph` functions works only when the column is called `name` within the node data. This might be an issue to report to `tidygraph`.

It is possible to do this directly with `tidygraph`, by using `igraph` functions, considering the following:

1. A `tbl_graph` object subclasses `igraph` so there is no need to convert your data to a tibble and then to an igraph from a data frame, you can directly run igraph functions to a `tbl_graph` object.
2. <s>It is possible to set a `node_key` argument when constructing your graph. This is passed onto `igraph` and therefore stored within its attributes. HOWEVER, using `node_id` as you did in your example will not work, as `igraph` uses this same name internally for the node indices, and therefore will be somehow overwritten. So if you call the column of your node keys different than "node_id" you can then set this as your `node_key` parameter.</s>
3. According to `tidygraph` it should be possible to pass a column name as a `node_key`, see [here](https://tidygraph.data-imaginist.com/reference/tbl_graph.html).

> **node_key** The name of the column in nodes that character represented to and from columns should be matched against. If NA the first column is always chosen. This setting has no effect if to and from are given as integers.

If the column with the IDs is called `name`, then this is also recognized by `igraph`, and will return named paths when calling a `shortest_paths()` function. However this seems to fail when passing any other node column as a `node_key`, so for this example we can call the column `name`.

See below your same code with these few modifications during construction, and the output you asked for.

```r
library(tidygraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

demo_netw <- tbl_graph(nodes = tibble(name = c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                       edges = tribble(~from, ~to,
                                       "B", "A",
                                       "D", "C",
                                       "A", "D"))

shortest_paths(demo_netw, "B", "C")$vpath
#> [[1]]
#> + 4/4 vertices, named, from e00d5b2:
#> [1] B A D C
```

Comment: Thank you! My confusion was caused by igraph not associating the edges with `node_id`. Because `node_id` behaves unexpectedly, it would be helpful if `tbl_graph()` could issue a warning to change the column name. It would also be nice if `convert(to_shortest_path)` could return the order of the nodes and edges as additional columns in the node data and edge data, respectively. Then one could keep the code completely tidygraph-based.
Just one small comment: the argument `node_key` can be omitted in this
example. It appears as if the first column name is by default chosen as `node_key`.

Comment: @MichaelGastner thank you for the remark. I checked and indeed `node_key` can be omitted because `tidygraph` defaults to `node_key = 'name'`. If set to `NA` it uses the first node column ([see here](https://tidygraph.data-imaginist.com/reference/tbl_graph.html)), i.e. the network construction should work with the column `node_id` and `node_key = NA`, but it doesn't. Strangely, to add any other column as a `node_key` there has to be a `name` column present, and this is the actual reason your code did not work. This might be an issue  worth reporting. I will update my answer to reflect this.