# Splitting a graph by a node

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory, tidygraph

I have a graph, which i would like to split by a node. Which is a presented below.

I am using R `tidygraph`. It has morph functionality with `to_split` and `to_components`, but i couldnot find proper documentation to implement it. Any leads will be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible option with `igraph`

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)
v <- "3"
v.neighbor <- neighbors(g, v)
v.new <- paste0(v, "_", seq_along(v.neighbor))
gout <- g %>%
    delete.vertices(v) %>%
    add.vertices(nv = length(v.neighbor), name = v.new) %>%
    add.edges(c(rbind(v.new, names(v.neighbor))))
```

and `plot(gout)` shows

[image]

## data

```
df <- data.frame(
    from = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 5),
    to = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. I have a follow-up question on using `igraph` functionalities on tidygraph object. Is there anything to keep in mind when using `igraph` functionalities on tidygraph. I have come across the following link where it says "passing this onto igraph functions works only when the column is called name within the node data. This might be an issue to report to tidygraph". Are there any such rules to be aware of.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65446626/tidygraph-obtain-sequence-of-nodes-along-shortest-path

Comment: @naveenchandra Sorry that I didn't use `tidygraph` before, so I may not be able to help you